# How to check which are the arguments of a jar script?

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to launch a jar script, but I am not sure about which arguments should I specify.

As `java -jar script.jar --help` does not work, do you know how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to see the source code of the script. A parameter like `--help` has to be implemented (either manually or by something like args4j) by the application in order to do something.

Comment: There are no generic arguments that a java program would support. As said above, what argument it would accept depends on the program and developer. You should either read the code, or read your program's documentation to find out.

Comment: You might want to consider reading the documentation for that jar.

Answer (score -1):

check the arguments of the file (main(String[] args)) where is used args

Comment: If you only have the executable jar file, you usually don't have access to the source code. Unless you want to bother with decompiling the class files. So this answer is not really useful.